# Unit test for dealloc with ARC in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, automatic-ref-counting

I'd like to write an iOS unit test for a `dealloc` method that (basically) removes the object as the delegate of another object.

```
- (void) dealloc {
    someObject.delegate = nil;
}
```

However I can't call `dealloc` directly when using ARC. What would be the best way to write this unit test?

Comment: You are also never supposed to call `dealloc` directly (except `[super dealloc]` in `dealloc`) when not using ARC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assign an instance to a weak variable:

```
MyType* __weak zzz = [[MyType alloc] init];
```

The instance will be dealloced right away.

Alternatively, [you can disable ARC on your unit test file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project) and call dealloc.

Comment: I don't see how you could write a useful test using a weak reference. If `zzz` is immediately deallocated, you'd be assigning nil as the delegate of `someObject`. So you'd be verifying that no-op assignment, not the behavior of deallocating `zzz`.

Comment: @chrispix It's true that `zzz` will be assigned `nil`, but ARC will also trigger a call to `MyType`'s deallocation code to undo the effects of `[[MyType alloc] init]`.

Comment: I get that. My point is that to test that the dealloc method above nils the delegate, you need to be able to say at some point `someObject.delegate = zzz`. With a weak reference, that's always a nil assignment, so someObject.delegate is always nil. The test may pass, but it'll also pass if you comment that line in dealloc. I think disabling ARC on the test class is the only clean way to test this.

Answer (score 6):

A better solution is simply

```
- (void)testDealloc
{
    __weak CLASS *weakReference;
    @autoreleasepool {
        CLASS *reference = [[CLASS alloc] init]; // or similar instance creator.
        weakReference = reference;

        // Test your magic here.
        [...]
    }
    // At this point the everything is working fine, the weak reference must be nil.
    XCTAssertNil(weakReference);
}
```

This works creating an instance to the class we want to deallocate inside `@autorealase`, that will be released (if we are not leaking) as soon as we exit the block. `weakReference` will hold the reference to the instance without retaining it, that will be set to `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually use a custom autorelease-pool to test dealloc-related behaviour:

```
- (void) testDealloc {
    id referencedObject = ...
    @autoreleasepool {
         id referencingObject = [ReferencingObject with:referencedObject];
         ...
    }
    // dealloc has been called on referencingObject here, unless you have a memory leak
    XCTAssertNil(referencedObject.delegate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swfit 5.3:

```swift
func test_myObject_dealloc() throws {
    weak var weakObject: MyObject?
    try autoreleasepool {
        let strongObject: MyObject = initializeMyObject(…)
        weakObject = strongObject
        XCTAssertNotNil(weakObject)
        // Perform your tests here…
    }
    XCTAssertNil(weakObject) 
}
```

Don't forget that you don't need the `throws` or `try` before `autoreleasepool` if your tests won't throw :)